# Google Maps (API v2) + jQuery UI Dialog, Non stoppable dragging problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

### **Hey!**

I'm using Google Maps API v2 (for some reason, it *has* to be the v2) and jQuery UI 1.8.6 (and jQuery 1.4.1).

**The situation is:** 
I have a map inside a modal dialog.

**The Problem is:**
When i click on the shadow of the info "balloon" and drag the map, it won't stop dragging.

I really don't know which **code** should i provide, so, if you want me to put some code specifically just let me know.

```
function createMarker(latitude, longitude, num, color, id_local) {

var iconOptions = {};
iconOptions.width = 32;
iconOptions.height = 32;
iconOptions.primaryColor = ''+color;
iconOptions.label = ''+num;
iconOptions.cornerColor = "#82c4e8";
iconOptions.strokeColor = "#000000";

var newIcon = MapIconMaker.createLabeledMarkerIcon(iconOptions);
//
var point = new GLatLng(latitude,longitude,0);
//
var marker = new GMarker(point, {
    icon: newIcon
});


var html = $('#info_mapa_'+id_local).html();
GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
});

return marker;
}
```

### Thank you.

Comment: Can you post all of the listeners; anything looking like this: `GEvent.addListener(`. It almost has to be an event handling problem. I'd venture to guess the reason they are using v2 is for the Earth plugin. http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1480

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll post the listeners as soon as possible. As for the reason we are using the v2 is, because my boss lost 5 hours trying to migrate to v3 and it didn't work out so smoothly (it didn't work out at all). And if he says so...

Comment: @JoshN Hope the code help you helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My boss decided to spent a day migrating to v3 and get rid of this stupid problem. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

<del>DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ofuze4</del>

DEMO: https://so.lucafilosofi.com/google-maps-api-v2-jquery-ui-dialog-non-stoppable-dragging-problem/

PSEUDO CODE:

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#j-dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        open: function() {
            initialize();
        }
    });
});
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( - 34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas")[0], myOptions);

    var contentString = $('#map-info').text();

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

var newIcon = 'http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/oxygen/48x48/actions/note2.png';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    icon: newIcon,
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: "Hello World!"
});

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
    function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
<style>#map_canvas { margin:0 auto; width:450px; height: 340px }</style>
```

HTML:

```
    <div title="google maps inside jquery dialog" id="j-dialog">    
      <div id="map_canvas">
      </div>  
    </div>
```

hope this help

**REFERENCE:**

> - http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately putting the google map inside the jUi dialog is not my problem. The problem is when I click on an info balloon shadow and drag the map, then it won't stop dragging.

Comment: Just a question, aren't you using api-v3 in that example?

Comment: the thing is "I'm using Google Maps API v2 (for some reason, it has to be the v2) and jQuery UI 1.8.6 (and jQuery 1.4.1)."

Comment: @Mario Cesar I ported the code from @aSeptik to Google Maps v2. http://jsbin.com/uxixe3/4 I'm thinking this might be easier to debug if you add the MapIconMaker object/constructor to jsbin, as I don't see any bugs in the current code. (Though it was ported somewhat slapdash, since my memory of v2 is fading.)

Comment: Thank you for your help guys but we realise that we had to move to v3 sooner or later, so we gave it another go and... it's all sorted out!